# Split values into Quartiles with case and aggregation statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregation, quartile

I have a Employee dataset like below. The start date is the employee's hire date and the end date is the date the employee left the employer. Both are in date datatype.

```
Gender   StartDate       EndDate
 M       2010-04-30      2013-06-18
 F       2010-01-09      2015-06-19
 M       2009-09-08      2014-08-13
```

I would like to divide employee data into quartiles based on average number of months of employment. The results also include the total number of employees(Employee Column), the percentage of employees who are Male, the percentage of employees who are female, and average number of months employed. Below please find the expected results:

```
Quartile    Employee    %Male   %Female   AvgMonths
1             20        60.00    40.00     8.75
2             25        50.00    50.00     28.5
3             10        40.00    60.00     41.25
```

I would like to get 25%, 50% and 75% quartile based on the number of months employed and take average to get AvgMOnths.

Below please find my query, I don't know where I can add the quartile calculation into the query.

```
declare @current date;
set @current='2012-12-31';

select count(*) as Employees,
       cast(cast(AVG(CASE WHEN Gender = 'M' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END)*100 as decimal(18,2)) as nvarchar(5)) +'%' as Male,
       cast(cast(AVG(CASE WHEN Gender = 'F' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END)*100 as decimal(18,2)) as nvarchar(5)) +'%' as Female,
       AVG(CASE WHEN EndDate is null then DATEDIFF(MONTH, StartDate, @current)
                when EndDate is not null then DATEDIFF(MONTH, StartDate, EndDate)
           end) as AvgMonths
from dbo.DimEmployee
```

-----------------------updates-------------------------------------

I figured out by myself. below please find the code:

```
declare @current date;
set @current='2012-12-31';
select count(*) as Employees,
       cast(cast(AVG(CASE WHEN Gender = 'M' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END)*100 as decimal(18,2)) as nvarchar(10)) +'%' as Male,
       cast(cast(AVG(CASE WHEN Gender = 'F' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END)*100 as decimal(18,2)) as nvarchar(10)) +'%' as Female,
       AVG(t.EmployedMonths) as AvgMonths,
       Ntile(3) over (order by t.EmployedMonths asc) as Quartiles
from
      (select EmployeeKey, Gender,
       CASE WHEN EndDate is null then abs(DATEDIFF(MONTH, StartDate, @current))
            when EndDate is not null then abs(DATEDIFF(MONTH, StartDate, EndDate))
            end as EmployedMonths
        from dbo.DimEmployee)t
group by t.EmployedMonths
```

Comment: What is the criteria to separate employees by quartile? You mentioned the *avrage number of months of employment*, but in your resultset both records have `AvgMonths = 10`.

Comment: How will you handle ties?

Comment: @GMB hi there, i'd like to split values into 25%, 50% and 75% quartiles. Sorry for my bad example, I have made up a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the quartile using `rank()` and `count(*)` as a window function:

```
select floor( rnk * 4.0 / cnt ) as quartile,
       count(*) as Employees,
       cast(cast(AVG(CASE WHEN Gender = 'M' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END)*100 as decimal(18,2)) as nvarchar(5)) + '%' as Male,
       cast(cast(AVG(CASE WHEN Gender = 'F' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END)*100 as decimal(18,2)) as nvarchar(5)) + '%' as Female,
       AVG(num_months * 1.0) as AvgMonths
from (select e.*,
             rank() over (partition by datediff(month, startdate, coalesce(enddate, @current))) - 1 as rnk,
             count(*) over () as cnt,
             datediff(month, startdate, coalesce(enddate, @current)) as num_months
      from dbo.DimEmployee e
     ) e
group by floor( rnk * 4.0 / cnt )
```

Comment: thanks. i didn't state that clear. the result is not what I'm looking for. I'd like to get 25%, 50% and 75% quartiles based on AvgMonths. In your example, it's not calculating all of them. And I don't understand why you multiple rank by 4?

Comment: @vivianna . . . `* 4` is the same as `/ 0.25`, which are the groups you want to break things into.  Note:  If you have ties, you might not have the appropriate quartiles.